# What exactly is a Cartesian product in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I often hear the word "Cartesian Product" from my co-workers when there's a Domain Model with a collection in a collection and eager fetch of the same. Let's say I have the below Model.

```
public class Order{
  List<Product> Products
}
public class Product{
  List<Units> Units
}
```

Now they say, If I try to Eager fetch Order with Products and Units, I'm supposed to get a Cartesian Product (aka duplicates ..).
But when i test it by enabling ShowSql I don't seem to get any duplicates.
This is my repository class

```
    public List<Order> GetOrdersWithProductsAndUnits()
    {
        return GetSession().Query<Order>()
                           .FetchMany(order => order.Products)
                           .ThenFetch(product => product.Units)
                           .ToList();
    }
```

And here's the sql output on enabling ShowSql. This seems fine and as expected with the join on the necessary tables.

```
select order0_.Id as Id8_0_, 
childstock1_.Id as Id23_1_,
childstock2_.Id as Id24_2_, 
order0_.CustomerName as Customer2_8_0_,  
order0_.City as City8_0_,
childstock1_.Size as Size23_1_,
childstock2_.Box as Box24_2_,
from Orders order0_  
left outer join Products childstock1_ on order0_.Id=childstock1_.OrderId  
left outer join Units childstock2_ on childstock1_.Id=childstock2_.ProductId
```

I had 125 Orders in my Database and when i eager fetch the orders with the Products and Units I still get 125 records.

```
List<Order> orders = repository.GetOrdersWithProductsAndUnits();
   Assert.That(orders.Count,Is.EqualTo(125));
```

Further when i check via the Visual Studio Debugger I don't find any duplicates inside the Order Collection at Products or Units level either.

I was expecting as many Orders as Units in my Database(close to 1000) because of a cartesian product resulting in duplicates. Am I missing something trivial, Is my understanding of Cartesian product skewed ? Or does the Query API that I'm using automatically solves Cartesian Products problem automatically.

FYI: I'm sure of the data setup as well. I've debugged through the Visual Studio Debugger and I notice Orders that have more than one Products and Products with more than one Units.

Any help/reference material is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the data is set up the way you say it is? Do the Orders have any Products associated with them?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure of it, I've debugged through Visual Studio Debug Window. Each Order has many Products and each Product has many Units.

Comment: Ok--the other thing is that NHibernate is reconciling the "extra" records-- have you tried running the SQL directly and viewing the results? Also, I don't *think* this could result in a cartesian product. Technically that would be joining every order against every product against every unit. I don't think this is possible without a cross join, but I could be wrong.

Comment: If I run the generated SQL query directly, I do get the expected 1000 records. And that's OK. I was expecting duplicates in my POCO objects itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to other query types (HQL, Criteria, QueryOver) NHibernate automatically discards duplicate root entities in Linq queries. But as you said in your last comment, you still get that many rows from the database, so your query might be slow.

Comment: yup, you're right. It turns out that NHibernate's LINQ API automatically does a DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer on the result set. Hence.. i was getting only distinct Order Ids, however, in those Orders I did find duplicated Products(as many products as the units).

Answer (score 1):

So the problem with a Cartesian Product, which you have here, is you are getting back way more rows than you need in the SQL because it returns copies of the order columns with exactly the same data for each child object.  So instead of getting the orders 125 times, it actually gets them 1000 times and "rolls up" behind the scenes into your order objects.  The columns that are repeated every time are: `order0_.Id, order0_.CustomerName, City8_0_`

Obviously you need to repeat the Order Id since that is the FK and exists in the remote tables.  But imagine if your Order object had far more columns and you did this on a dataset with millions of child row.

Using something like HibernatingRhinos will help you immensely.  I've used their EF tool and avoided many problems with Cartesian products that I had no idea were occurring otherwise.  The main culprit with ORMs creating Cartesian products is typically eager loading/deep reads of your object tree.  It can easily be avoided with model objects **based on views** instead of trying to build results sets by linking objects together in client code.